# How to paginate complex mongoDB queries in Grails?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

I have three domain classes Author, Comment and Book:

```
class Author {
String name
static hasMany = [books: Book, comments: Comment]
}

class Book {
static belongsTo = [author: Author]
static hasMany = [comments: Comment]
}

class Comment {
static belongsTo = [book: Book, author: Author] 
}
```

I have the following mongoDB query to find all the books which have comments from a given author.

```
Comment.findAllByAuthor(author1).collect {
        it.book
    }.unique().findAll { 
        it != null 
}
```

How can I use pagination for this query, i.e., to paginate over all the books?

Answer (score 1):

Use criteria query with Book instead of Comment:

```
def c = Book.createCriteria()
def PaginatedBookList = c.list(max: params.max, offset: params.offset) {
    and{
        eq('author',author1)
        isNotNull('comments')
    }
}
```